# Click a HTML element and trigger the next() available hyperlink?

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, triggers

I would like an element to trigger the next available  on the page.

```
$("span.topic").click(function(){
    $("span.topic").next("a.page").trigger('click');
});

<div> 
    <span class="topic">Topic 1</span>
    <a class="page" href="http://www.google.com">Welcome to the first Topic</a>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "an element"?

Comment: Are you trying to have the '.topic' span navigate to google?

Comment: a.page and span.topic go to the same place. However the span can't not be an a element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ovoqal/5/edit)

```
$('.topic').on('click', function(){
  window.location.href = $(this).next('a').attr('href');
});
```

Comment: That won't trigger any click handlers/events associated with that particular `a` element.

Comment: The link is dynamically generated by php

Comment: @NickRivers sorry for not following up, I was away. I read your comments and now I see you accepted my answer now I'm interested: Where was the issue? Happy coding and thx

Comment: Well honestly this was the best solution, if my problem was the question I posted. My real problem was a little bit more complicated.

Comment: Ah, that explains everything :) well, hope you solved your issue! take care!

Answer (score 0):

use `this` so it knows which element to start from

```
$("span.topic").click(function(){
    $(this).next("a.page").click();
});
```

or if there will be elements in between the span and anchor..

```
$("span.topic").click(function(){
    $(this).nextAll("a").first().click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are using so many unnecessary selectors. Use:

```
$("span.topic").click(function(){
    $(this).next().click();
});
```

Comment: Unnecessary selectors? Your attitude is unnecessary.

Comment: @NickRivers Alright, you're welcome to that opinion. Nevertheless, the selectors are unnecessary. I'm not trying to be a dick about it, they are.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the `<span class='topic'>Topic 1</span>` to navigate on click you wont' be able to do that by triggering an anchor tag's click event.  The browser will not navigate using that method.

You can however change the `window.location.href` to what `httt://www.google.com`.

Try this:

```
$("span.topic").click(function(){
    window.location.href = $("span.topic").next("a.page").attr('href');
});
```

This is a solution to what you are attempting but it's not a very pragmatic way to reference a URL you want to navigate to.  Is there a reason you wouldn't just wrap you span in the anchor tag like this?

```
<div> 
    <a class="page" href="http://www.google.com">
        <span class="topic">Topic 1</span>
        Welcome to the first Topic
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: this is already answered. Also Read the DOCS about the use of `$(this)`

Comment: Yes, I'm using some complicated PHP that was passed down to me.

Comment: It wasn't answered when I started writing my answer.  :)  I left his implementation of the javascript as close to in tact as possible so that it would be clear what I changed.  I'm familiar with how to use $(this).

Comment: Gotcha.  If you can't adjust the markup then the solutions using window.location.href given will work.